# IOS maximum number of nib files allowed in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios, nib

Is there is any limitation on the number of nib files can be used in a application.
In my application I am using 50 nib files will there be any memory issue as i have to load this nib files on run time.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why so many nibs?

Comment: i am working on an app which will work on both iphone and ipad.Also i am using different nib files for landscape and portrait orientation.I am still not sure if this is acceptable way of doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a limit, but even though you have hundreds of NIB's they won't be loaded into the memory at the same time. The view's of a iPhone application is lazely loaded. This is more a question on how a large an application can be. Those files are only XML (*which again is compiled to binary as commented*) files describing your layout so I would suppose that the number must be many times what you asked of before it can be an issue, and even then this is a question on how large an application can be and not RAM.

***Updated***

> App Size Tips (For iOS Apps Only)
>   Apps can be as large as 2GB, but 
>   be aware of download times.
>   Make efforts to minimize file size.
>   Remember there is a 20MB limit for Over the Air downloads

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf

Comment: nib files in the app are not xml, they are binary archives and much smaller than the xib xml  files in Xcode.

Comment: @CocoaFu Apple (and thus developers) use the term nib and xib interchangeably. Wether it's a nib or a xib is an implementation detail because Xcode compiles xibs down to binary when you build.

Comment: @codecaffeine The point is that the nib files in the app are not xml, they are smaller binary files.

Comment: @CocoaFu yes, you are technically right. I just think the xib vs. nib discussion is confusing the original question and it doesn't really matter since xibs get compiled into nibs when you build the app.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between .xib files (in Xcode) and .nib files in the app. .xib files are xml and .nib files are binary archives.

The sizes are also drastically different, in an app I have a .xib file was 45,124 bytes but the .nib file in the app was 4,823 bytes.

ALso more nib files can be good design, each nib containing one UI concept.

Comment: While this is technically true, please be aware that Xcode compiles .xib files into binary .nib files when you build an app. In fact, you can do this manually (type 'man ibtool' in the terminal to see how). There is no reason to use .nib files over .xib files, especially since .xib files play nicer with version control.

Comment: @codecaffeine I am not saying to use nib over xib.  I am saying that the nib files in the app are not xml and are smaller than the xib files.

Comment: yeah, but it doesn't matter in the app because it gets compiled down to a nib anyway. Especially in the context of this question.

Comment: The point is not to look at the zib file sizes in Xcode to try to determine the effect on the app size.  @codecaffeine what change would you like in my answer?

Comment: I don't think anybody was looking at xib file sizes in Xcode to try to determine the effect on the app size. That's why your answer confused me. It was wether there are any memory (or other) issues with using a lot of nibs. Which there aren't because they're lazily loaded. Your answer is 100% correct, but talking about the difference between xib and nib sizes didn't seems to pertain to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but I think loading object instances from nib files has a little RAM overhead. When the objects are loaded however, they probably consume the same amount of RAM as 'regular' instances.

So I think it comes down to the complexity of these nib files.

Then again, I'm not sure so don't take my word for it ;).